# asp.net: data adapter converts apostrophe to &#39; when inserting row to sql server -- can this be prevented?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an asp.net subroutine that takes a selected gridview row and inserts it into a SQL Sever table by a data adapter. Everything works great... until a string contains a single apostrophe. This is valid, because it's a name field, an example of this is "O'Neil".  What it gets converted to is "O'Neil".

Is there some way to prevent this?  I converted my insert command into a parameterized statement, but it didn't solve the problem.  The code I'm posting below is assembled from online examples and "solutions." I'm really hoping it's something really simple I'm missing (one can only hope :) ).

- I tried converting the single quote (when detected) to a double quote.
- I tried directly placing the variable value into the insertcommand string.
- I rebuilt it from scratch in case some typos got smuggled in.
- I have "Strict=True" and "Explicit=true" to make sure the obvious bugs get caught and smashed.

So whatever is happening now is valid code, but is converting the apostrophe to a web code.

I'm only posting the subroutine I'm trying to troubleshoot.  Thank you for any insight.

```
Protected Sub btnReconcile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim connectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conn_MIA_2014_15_v1").ConnectionString

    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim insertString As String
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()


    connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    Dim Campus As String
    Dim Student_ID As Integer
    Dim Student_Name As String
    Dim Enrolled As String
    Dim Date_Returned As Date
    Dim Count_Absent_Days As Integer
    Dim Chronic_Health As String
    Dim Date_Of_Behavior As Date
    Dim Total_Days_Suspended As Integer


    For Each item As GridViewRow In Me.GridView1.Rows
        If CType(item.Cells(0).FindControl("cbSelect"), CheckBox).Checked Then

            Campus = item.Cells(1).Text
            Student_ID = CInt(item.Cells(2).Text)
            Student_Name = item.Cells(3).Text
            Enrolled = item.Cells(4).Text
            Date_Returned = CDate(item.Cells(5).Text)
            Count_Absent_Days = CInt(item.Cells(6).Text)
            Chronic_Health = item.Cells(7).Text
            Date_Of_Behavior = CDate(item.Cells(8).Text)
            Total_Days_Suspended = CInt(item.Cells(9).Text)

            insertString = "insert into TC_Audit_More_Than_8_Days_WO_Entry_CH_Sus_Rec " & _
                "(Campus,Student_ID,Student_Name,Enrolled,Date_Returned,Count_Absent_Days,Chronic_Health,Date_Of_Behavior,Total_Days_Suspended) " & _
                "values (@Campus,@Student_ID,@Student_Name,@Enrolled,@Date_Returned,@Count_Absent_Days,@Chronic_Health,@Date_Of_Behavior,@Total_Days_Suspended)"

            adapter.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(insertString, connection)

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Campus", Campus)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_ID", Student_ID)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_Name", Student_Name)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enrolled", Enrolled)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Returned", Date_Returned)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Count_Absent_Days", Count_Absent_Days)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Chronic_Health", Chronic_Health)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Of_Behavior", Date_Of_Behavior)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Days_Suspended", Total_Days_Suspended)

            Try
                connection.Open()
                adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            connection.Close()
        End If
    Next


    Me.GridView1.DataBind()
    Me.GridView2.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Not very familiar with gridviews. Is there a way to get the raw text instead of the display text? I'm assuming you're just grabbing the wrong one somehow. You most likely want to use cell.Value instead of cell.Text but I'm not positive

Comment: Nevermind the gridview. Just imagine the variables as magic genies that _are_ mapped correctly to the source and that the values going into them are correct. All i'm trying to prevent is the html encode that seems to happen against my wishes. I can't seem to find any command to switch it off.

Comment: Where is the data originating? If you don't want it to be treated as html encoded text, put it into an input field instead or something. Or htmldecode it before saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just to be sure we're on the same page, you *have* tried the insert statement using two single quotes, correct? Because I'm not seeing that in your code. It should be something like this:

```
Protected Sub btnReconcile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim connectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conn_MIA_2014_15_v1").ConnectionString

    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim insertString As String
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()


    connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    Dim Campus As String
    Dim Student_ID As Integer
    Dim Student_Name As String
    Dim Enrolled As String
    Dim Date_Returned As Date
    Dim Count_Absent_Days As Integer
    Dim Chronic_Health As String
    Dim Date_Of_Behavior As Date
    Dim Total_Days_Suspended As Integer


    For Each item As GridViewRow In Me.GridView1.Rows
        If CType(item.Cells(0).FindControl("cbSelect"), CheckBox).Checked Then

            Campus = item.Cells(1).Text
            Student_ID = CInt(item.Cells(2).Text)
            Student_Name = item.Cells(3).Text
            Enrolled = item.Cells(4).Text
            Date_Returned = CDate(item.Cells(5).Text)
            Count_Absent_Days = CInt(item.Cells(6).Text)
            Chronic_Health = item.Cells(7).Text
            Date_Of_Behavior = CDate(item.Cells(8).Text)
            Total_Days_Suspended = CInt(item.Cells(9).Text)

            insertString = "insert into TC_Audit_More_Than_8_Days_WO_Entry_CH_Sus_Rec " & _
                "(Campus,Student_ID,Student_Name,Enrolled,Date_Returned,Count_Absent_Days,Chronic_Health,Date_Of_Behavior,Total_Days_Suspended) " & _
                "values (@Campus,@Student_ID,@Student_Name,@Enrolled,@Date_Returned,@Count_Absent_Days,@Chronic_Health,@Date_Of_Behavior,@Total_Days_Suspended)"

            adapter.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(insertString, connection)

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Campus", Campus)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_ID", Student_ID)
            ' I modified the line below...
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_Name", Replace(Student_Name,"&#39;","''") '<-- see what I did there?
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enrolled", Enrolled)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Returned", Date_Returned)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Count_Absent_Days", Count_Absent_Days)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Chronic_Health", Chronic_Health)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Of_Behavior", Date_Of_Behavior)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Days_Suspended", Total_Days_Suspended)

            Try
                connection.Open()
                adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            connection.Close()
        End If
    Next


    Me.GridView1.DataBind()
    Me.GridView2.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: I already tried that, but I'll try it again in case I did it wrong before.

Comment: Actually I forgot the semi-colon too. I had to do this at one point before, but I forget how I handled it safely. In the end, @Avitus is probably correct :-/

Comment: Just 2 characters needed to be added: this is what worked for me.  adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_Name", Replace(Student_Name, "&#39;", "'"))  Thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah, and it needed a single quote rather than two single quotes.

Comment: You should probably stop using AddWithValue. I actually think it's deprecated anyway. Instead use `command.Parameters.Add("@Student_Name", nvarchar,200).Value = Replace(Student_Name, "&#39;","'")` This assumes your field is nvarchar(200); obviously you would adjust this type and size as necessary.

Comment: I had tried that approach in one of my failed iterations and didn't switch back. Good idea.

Comment: Just keep in mind to use the appropriate size field in VB.NET. Max = -1. SQL nulls = nothing; etc.

Comment: You mean in the command.Parameters.Add argument? Got that covered. Or did you mean something else entirely?

Comment: No, that's it. I know I had errors like that before I found the correct sql-to-vb size conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same problem. I searched a lot. finally I solved it by changing content type of page to

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="true" Debug="true" ContentType="application/xhtml+xm" %>
```